# Can I use both WebMethods *and* ASP.net UpdatePanel on the same page?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, webmethod, pagemethods

I have an ASP.net page with two web methods.  Everything worked fine until I tried to add an ASP.net UpdatePanel.  The UpdatePanel works, but now I can't call my web methods.  They fail and return the following error: `"Message":" is not a valid valid for Int16..."`

I can place a breakpoint on the first line of my web method and it won't be hit; so that tells me something about where the error is coming from.

Anyhow, is it practical to use web methods and UpdatePanels on the same page?

Comment: It's not wise to use update panels at all if I may say so... ;)

Comment: Are you calling the WebMethods from within the UpdatePanel?

Comment: I am calling the WebMethods from within JavaScript functions.

Comment: @Robert, I agree that UpdatePanels may not always be the best thing to use, but I like having them in my toolbox to use from time to time.

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies: You're saying: "*UpdatePanels may not always be the best thing to use*" and I say: "*UpdatePanels are **almost never** the thing to use*". I intentionally left out the word *best* :) But it's true that one using Asp.net WebForms may not have better ways of doing it. I would still rather say that if you're already using web methods, you may not need update panels at all. Which would be much much better and you can then easily resort to using helper libs like jQuery or similar.

Comment: @Robert, if you think that `UpdatePanel`s are almost never the thing to use, perhaps you can advise me. I have a `GridView` table on my page (which is rendered in server-side code). I want the user to be able to add a row to the table without posting back.  I can use jQuery to add the row, but if the table is empty, then I would have to add the header columns too.  Furthermore, I must repeat myself line-by-line in the JavaScript code to add/update rows, which is a major code-smell.  It seems easiest to just use the `UpdatePanel`, but if you know a better way, by all means, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I must apologize to those who have read my question so far.  I discovered a subtle bug that I introduced into my code at the same time I added the ASP.net UpdatePanel.

Normally, I would just delete my question, but since the question has not been previously asked, I'm going to answer my own question:

#### Yes it's possible to use both `UpdatePanel` and `WebMethod` within the same page

... for anyone else who wants to know.

Comment: Maybe you should as well explain the bug, so one won't repeat the same mistake.

Comment: The bug had to do with adding a new  `record ID` field to a form on my page which was used for updating existing records in my database, but not for adding new records.  Since this field was an integer in server-side code, leaving it blank caused the JSON serializer to try to convert an empty string to an integer and fail.  It didn't occur to me to try both operations before concluding incorrectly that it had something to do with the `UpdatePanel`.  As you can see, it is only tangentially related to my question.